# How to find common adjectives related to a world using word2vec?

Tags: python, word2vec

I need to train a model in Python based on word2vec or other models in order to get adjectives which are semantically close to a world.

For example give a word like 'cat' to model and receive adjectives like 'cute', 'nice', etc.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

With any word2vec model – whether you train it on your own data, or download someone else's pre-trained model – you can give it a word like `cat` and receive back a ranked list of words that are considered 'similar' in its coordinate system.

However, these won't normally be limited to adjectives, as typical word2vec models don't take any note of a word's part-of-speech. So to filter to just adjectives, some options could include:

- use a typical word2vec set-of-vectors that is oblivious to part-of-speech, but use some external reference (like say WordNet) to check each returned word, and discard those that can't be adjectives
- preprocess a suitable training corpus to label words with their part-of-speech before word2vec training, as is sometimes done. Then your model's tokens will include within them a declared part-of-speech. For example, you'd then no longer have the word `good` alone as a token, but (depending on what conventions you use) tagged-tokens like `good/NOUN` & `good/ADJ` instead. Then, filtering the closest-words to just adjectives is a simple matter of checking for the desired string pattern.

However, the words you receive from any such process based on word2vec might not be precisely what you're looking for. The kinds of 'semantic similarity' captured by word2vec coordinates are driven by how well words predict other nearby words under the model's limitations. Whether these will meet your needs is something you'll have to try; there could be surprises.

For example, words that humans consider antonyms, like `hot` & `cold`, will still be relatively close to each other in word2vec models, as they both describe the same aspect of something (its temperature), and often appear in the same surrounding-word contexts.

And, depending on training texts & model training parameters, different word2vec models can sometimes emphasize different kinds of similarity in their rankings. Some have suggested, for example, that using a smaller `window` can tend to place words that are *direct replacements* for each other (same syntactic roles) closer together, whereas a larger `window` will somewhat more bring together words used in the same topical domains (even if they aren't of the same type). Which kind of similarity would be better for your need? I'm not sure; if you have the time/resources, you could compare the quality of results from multiple contrasting models.